# Python Numpy DTYPE dynamic array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a code like this

```
np.fromfile( f,
             dtype = np.dtype( [ ( 'f1', np.float16 ),
                                 ( 'f2', np.float16 )
                                 ]
                               ), 
             count = -1
             )
```

and I need to make a **`dtype`** dependent on variable ( instead of `size=2` make `size=var` ).

Tried to google it and tried to ask on IRC but no rescue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean dependent on variable? could you please provide an example of what you want to do and why it isn't working as expected? Also, please properly format your code

Comment: `np.dtype` takes a list of tuples.  You could construct such a list with code - list comprehension, append, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the individual dtypes are the same, and you aren't picky about names, this dtype format is easy to use and generalize:
    In [358]: dt = np.dtype('f,f,f')
    In [359]: dt
    Out[359]: dtype([('f0', '

Or with the common string join:

```
In [360]: dt = np.dtype(','.join(['f']*3))
In [361]: np.ones((3,), dtype=dt)
Out[361]: 
array([( 1.,  1.,  1.), ( 1.,  1.,  1.), ( 1.,  1.,  1.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
```

Or with list zip

```
In [364]: dt = [('foo%s'%n, fmt) for n,fmt in zip(range(3),'ifd')]
In [365]: dt
Out[365]: [('foo0', 'i'), ('foo1', 'f'), ('foo2', 'd')]
In [366]: np.ones(2, dtype=dt)
Out[366]: 
array([(1,  1.,  1.), (1,  1.,  1.)],
      dtype=[('foo0', '<i4'), ('foo1', '<f4'), ('foo2', '<f8')])
```